# event listener for range input not working for internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

My code seems to work in firefox and chrome but not in in internet explorer! it's a simple event event listener that take's the vale from a range input during the "input" event.

```
<range id="vol" min="0" max="1" step="0.001"/>

$('#vol').bind('input',function(){
var curr_vol = $('#vol').val();
alert("curr_vol");
});
```

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried the `change` event rather than `input`, I suspect that IE may not have (yet) implemented that, but without knowing which version of IE it's difficult to say for sure.

Comment: yes that might be possible however, if I do use the change event, it will defeat the entire purpose of having volume control slider

Comment: tried using the change event too.. the event just did not fire!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

did you try the mousemove event?

The input event is buggy in IE.
if you would use a range input, then the mousemove event can be an alternative.

Comment: How did this get marked as an appropriate answer!? How does this help future SO users without at least an explanation and example?

Comment: is this better?